# interdependency of 2 columns SQL

Tags: sql

Asking for help as I am stuck with the following SQL problem:

basically I have 2 columns that are dependent to each other,

like column 1's calculation is partially based on the lag of column 2, and column 2 = xxx + column 1.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

### Column 1, which selects a lag of the column final stock (column 2):

```
       , case when (lag(final_stock, 1) over (partition by d.material_code order by d.id) - lag(plan_units, 1) over (partition by d.material_code order by d.id)) < 0 then otr_units
                         else sales_unit
         end as stock_forecast
```

### Column 2, which is the sum of another column + the Column 1 (stock forecast):

```
       , (actual_stock + stock_forecast) as final_stock
```

It is worth mentioning that I am not able to use another column as a workaround.

Any solutions ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.